# Can I have a 200 amp rated box but only run 100 amp service

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Is this permissible if I get an inspection? I know that I won't be drawing 200 A but if I ever want to do a service upgrade and go with the 200 A incoming Service I'll have that possibility instead of changing out my whole box.

Comment: I'm curious, what does this save you compared to just doing 200A now?  Does the utility charge you a higher installation fee or a much higher fixed fee for 200A service?  Is your home miles from the pole?

Comment: Indeed. I have 400A service in part because the price from the utility (install and monthly) was **exactly the same** for 100, 200 or 400 (Class 320) so the only upcharge was an additional panel and larger wires on my part.

Answer (score 12):

Yes.  So long as you use the correct main breaker you can *and should* do this.

You may as well ensure any conduit from the meter to the main panel is also big enough for 200A service.   And while you're at it, any conduit from the meter to the roof, and/or *certainly* any underground conduit is all sized for 200A.

It's an unusual install so if you haven't purchased the panel yet, make sure to choose one that *has* a suitably rated 100A main breaker, and that such breaker and any necessary parts to install it are available for purchase in your time frame.  Don't take that for granted.  If what you want to do is allowed but you can't find the parts, you may need to install cascaded boxes (with the main breaker in a meter main or a tiny 100A panel) or to use a back-fed breaker as a main (which your inspector may not like).

All of this begs the question of why not just install 200A service now?  Unless you are miles from the pole I can't see the reason.  (Or, not miles ... because then you'd put a transformer at your end.  But some distance that is short enough for a 240V line and long enough to make the cable the overwhelming cost in this installation.)

Comment: I'll upvote this if you explain how to put a 100A main breaker in a 200A panelboard.

Comment: @RobertChapin that's not the question. The question is can there be a 200a main breaker in the panel if there's only 100a of service provided to it. The answer is just as much "Yes" as if someone asks about feeding a subpanel with a 100a "main breaker" (i.e. local shut off) from a 60a breaker in the main panel. Both work the exact same way.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't agree.  The question never mentioned a main breaker.  But you're welcome to edit the question.  

Comment: @RobertChapin  maybe a 100A meter main into a 200A panel with no main breaker.  Maybe a clamped 100A back feed.  Maybe OP hasn't bought the panel yet so just needs to find one that has a 100A main breaker that is rated and suitable for it.  Maybe *you already know* that there is no such thing ... in which case it would be helpful if you marked *down* my answer and wrote a new one saying "this would be allowed if it were possible, but there is no such thing suitably built and rated to do what you want".

Comment: @jay613 Or you could just paste that into the answer so I can upvote it.  

Comment: @RobertChapin ok ... done .... not to "earn the vote" but because your question turned out to be more interesting than I first thought.

Answer (score 10):

### It's only a maximum

As the judge explained to me, the 112 MPH tire rating *is a maximum rating*. It is safe to drive slower than that!

Same for electrical panels. A 200A bus rating means "Don't feed it 250A".  It is happy as a clam on a 60A, 100A, 125A or 150A service.

**In fact, you WANT a 200A panel.  100A panels have too few breaker spaces for a full house**. We regularly see people blocked on projects because their panel is full, and our experience is 30 is not enough for a house. **Spaces are cheap** so it's better to buy plenty of spaces now than have a problem later.  40-space is the largest panel before they start getting expensive, and so that's what we recommend.

### Getting a 100A main breaker

Now, how do you get a main breaker into it?  That takes a "large frame size" main breaker (most manufacturers have 2 frame sizes), but they do make 100A breakers in the large frame size.  So the main breaker can simply be swapped out, and leave the 200A in the bottom of the panel for the happy day you upgrade.

Even if that were not so, and the local inspector were amenable, all modern panels provide **generator interlocks**.  So you stick a 100A "generator breaker" in the panel with a tie-down kit and an interlock, and wire the 100A to your service.  The 200A main breaker thus goes to the generator inlet (which may also need an inline breakered disconenct if the AHJ wants smaller than 200A breaker protection on it).  Of course you could omit the inlet if you don't want that yet.

### The better DIY-friendly way: Meter-main

The ideal solution is to come up to NEC 2020 code, and install a **meter-main** at the meter. This integrates the meter with the main breaker.  It can be locked to deter vandals (the fire department has a [master key](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-24-in-Bolt-Cutter-With-7-16-in-Max-Cut-Capacity-48-22-4024/303182052)).

From an installation perspective, that means the cable run from your meter-main to your master panel (with all your breakers) is breaker-protected and therefore unrestricted, and does not need to be very close to the meter.  That means you have much more freedom as to where to put it.

It also means you are free to put the panel inside, which means your costly GFCI and AFCI breakers won't be deteriorated by the weather.

Same deal with the meter-main: change the main breaker to 100A.

Your AHJ might let you run with a 200A meter-main but a 100A main breaker in the main panel.  Code requires the Disconnect be located outside, not the main breaker. So the 200A would serve as the NEC 2020 outside disconnect, while the 100A main breaker would serve as the true main breaker.  And since the wires are breaker protected, you still get the freedom of location.  The AHJ might require 4/0 aluminum wire for the meter-main to panel run.  But aluminum is cheap. Semi-cheap.

Having a meter-main is a huge boon to DIY, since you can totally de-energize the panel with all the breakers. If you do the setup in the last paragraph, and use 4/0 wire for the service entrance (weatherhead to meter-main), you could DIY all your panel work when you upgrade to 200A.

A traditional main-breaker panel can't be DIYed because the service conductors landing on the main breaker are always-hot. It requires power company consent to de-energize them, and for that they need permits.

Comment: Good answer.  Only lost sight of the "run 100 amp service" part at the end there.  If Judson is planning 100A outside, unsure if the 200A meter main still makes sense.  I imagined someone throwing a nice big panelboard on to existing cable.  The ideas are still good for many situations.

Comment: @RobertChapin Yeah, but I think the fix there is careful labeling. 200A main but 100A disconnect raises a question that should be examined.

Comment: That was *not* what I expected when you said "master key"! :-)